# jQuery click event fired twice in firefox but not in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, click

I've got an image like this:

```
<img class="linkDelete" src="some_path"/>
```

I use jQuery click event on the image:

```
$('.linkDelete').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(location).attr('href', some_location);
});
```

The event is fired twice in Firefox but once in IE. I'd like to know if there's a solution to make it fire only once in Firefox? Thanks :)

PS: I tried by deleting the href="#" in the img tag. No use...

Comment: I suspect the issue lies in your other code, I'll knock up a quick JS fiddle

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qJLVx/ seems to be working fine. Although you need a `src` attribute on your `img` tag, which I added. I am not sure what `href` is for, as it only applies to `a` tags. Remember to only run the code you pasted above once, on page load, and not inside any kind of button otherwise you will bind it twice or more and it'll trigger multiple times.

Comment: `href` is not an image attribute. Considering just the code you've shared, it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The href is a Rest service which delete things in the database, it is why there's problem with that.

Comment: I tried other things in the jsfiddle, seems no problem there. That's pretty strange

Comment: wceo doesn't use `$(this).attr();` but `$(location).attr();` so it doesn't mean that the href attribute is for img tag ;)

Comment: @Oliboy50 Check the OP HTML markup at the beginning of the question.

Comment: @MelanciaUK yes but `$(location)` is not equal to `$('.linkDelete')` here... Edit : Oh ok, didn't see the href attribute :( Sorry

Comment: @Oliboy50 I got your point, but the original HTML markup is invalid. I'm not talking about the JS bits.

Comment: Is this code loaded via ajax?

Comment: Where's this piece of code in your page? Header? Body? Is it being loaded just once (ie: document ready)?

Comment: @Populus No, it's loaded directly

Comment: @MelanciaUK it is in body, loaded with $(window).load

Comment: Just a try: add the code event.stopPropagation() to the event handler and come back with the results please.

Comment: @peterfoldi Still same error...

Comment: another question: add the code console.log($('.linkDelete').length) (or alert if you wish) and check the results.

Comment: @peterfoldi it prints out 1...